# Apache Zeppelin 0.7.2 and spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7 on Windows 10 machine

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am new to zeppelin and try to configure apache zeppelin to connect with stand alone spark on my local machine, I set below settings in zeppelin-env.cmd file.  And change port no to 8082 in zeppelin-site.xml file.

```
    set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
    set SPARK_HOME=C:\tmp\spark\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7
```

Started spark master and worker like below
spark-class2.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
spark-class2.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://192.168.99.1:7077

Started zeppelin zeppelin.cmd and change spark interpreter settings as below. 
Change master to point to local spark master to spark://192.168.99.1:7077 and change useHiveContext to false.

When I try to run default out of box notebook I am getting below error.

> org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

```
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.start(RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java:143)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.reference(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:73)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:265)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:430)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.getFormType(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:111)
at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:387)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:329)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: ERROR [2017-07-09 20:50:13,161] ({pool-2-thread-2} Job.java[run]:188) - Job failed
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.start(RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java:143)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.reference(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:73)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:265)

Comment: ERROR [2017-07-09 20:50:13,165] ({pool-2-thread-2} NotebookServer.java[afterStatusChange]:2050) - Error
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.start(RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java:143)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.reference(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:73)
        at

Comment: Could you try dockerized zeppelin 0.7.2? `docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm -v $PWD/logs:/logs -v $PWD/notebook:/notebook -e ZEPPELIN_LOG_DIR='/logs' -e ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_DIR='/notebook' --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.7.2`

Comment: @Jitendra I am facing the same issue , is there any fix found ...i am trying on window 8 r2 OS.